# Finding the total number of rows in DGV after filling

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a form and one data grid view ....

I am filling the datagrid view by uisng the below method

```
 private void EquipmentFinder_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

        productgridview.RowTemplate.Height = 130;

        var productsbycount = dbentity.products.GroupBy(x => x.product_Id)
                              .Select(a => new
                               {
                                     productid = a.Key,
                                     productnam = a.FirstOrDefault().product_Name,
                                     productimage = a.FirstOrDefault().product_Image,
                                     productdescr = a.FirstOrDefault().product_Description,
                                     stockavailable = a.Select(x=>x.product_Id).Distinct().Count()
                                      productprice = a.FirstOrDefault().product_Price
                               });

        productbindingsource.DataSource = productsbycount;
        productgridview.DataSource = productbindingsource; 
 }
```

that was fine ....

now I want to find the total number of rows in the datagrid view(Row Count) and i want to represent this in label......

would any one pls help on this by giving any solution.....

Many Thanks ......

Comment: The obvious way is to query productsbycount for a count before binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
productgridview.Rows.Count;
```

should give you the number of rows in the DataGridView.
If you then want to set a label to have that text,

```
label.Text = productgridview.Rows.Count.ToString();
```

will set the label to display with the number of rows.

Answer (score 3):

just do

```
labelCount.Text = productgridview.Rows.Count.ToString("n0");
```

what is the problem with this?

Comment: thanks a lot for `"n0"` format I really like this small finishing touch +1
I wish you update your answer with more formats details